# How to execute custom emacs keybindings when CUA MODE is enabled?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, cua-mode

C-v originally in emacs moves one screenful, but when in cua mode, it yanks text. So, how do I move one screenful again in cua mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `PageDown` key, aka `<next>`.  It is bound to command `cua-scroll-up`.

(You should consult the doc for CUA mode for such questions. It should let you know what keys are bound to normally-bound keys that it usurps.)